# can pickle and socket connect without internet

Tags: python

I am sending data via pickle and socket as found here: [Socket Programming in Python using Pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576851/socket-programming-in-python-using-pickle). I am running 2 scripts with different environments and they are communicating with each other. I plan to have this not connected to the network. i.e. no wifi. As I understand it, since they are connected on the same pc, they should still work right or do I need wifi?

P.S. I am not asking for any code, it is done, working, all I am asking is that would something like this work without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely use [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) or even local servers on the same computer and it should work without a connection to the broader internet.